# How can I change written data in different positions of a file?

Tags: java, file-io

I am writing some information in a file and I want to update some part of this information. For instance:

If we assume the current context of the file is following sentences:

> This cake is made by Mary. 12
>
> Students play football.**12908**
>
> She is a teacher.546

Then I want to change 12908 to 765 in that file and write two new lines.The context of the file after changes would be like this:

> This cake is made by Mary. 12
>
> Students play football. **765**
>
> She is a teacher.546
>
> **I love my mother.**
>
> **The sky is bule. 897**

I want to update information many times in a file.  How can I do this?

Comment: Start by reading the file line-by-line and writing each line (or corrected line) into another file, and take it from there.

Comment: @lfasin The number of the lines is huge and your solution is not efficient for my condition, I am looking for a way so can read and change specific line not all lines.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about reading and writing so few lines you can use java's class [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) which fits exactly to your needs, but by experience i can tell that if you need to deal with a considerable amount of data IO, this is very inefficient . In that case as suggested by alfasin: "Start by reading the file line-by-line and writing each line (or corrected line) into another file, and take it from there".

[Here's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html) a tutorial on how to use RandomAccessFile.